# Where is the "Canvas" option in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm new to Xcode and when reading a tutorial, it tells me to do this in my storyboard file:

> First, click on the view controller and go to `Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles`

I'm with the interface builder opened but I can't see where is the "Canvas" option (or menu, I don't know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Canvas` option (under `Editor`) is only available if you have a .xib file selected in Project Navigator.

Comment: Nothing happens. Maybe because the Stardard Editor is already been shown right? Ok. But I still can't find that option.

Comment: Maybe I should change the question to "Where is the Canvas option?" or something like that.

Comment: Oh, are you talking about interface builder?

Comment: First you have to select the .xib file in your 'Project Navigator' - the file-tree on your left. Then this option (Editor->Canvas->Show Bounds Recatngles) will be available for you from the menu

Comment: Good to hear! XCode can be confusing first couple of years ;) They just merged Interface Builder and XCode into a single app a few months ago and this is the result.